# sorting advance datagrid columns in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, flex3, advanceddatagrid

I have four columns in advance datagrid like company, contact_person, product and date. I want to sort by product followed by company and followed by date. How can I do this in Advance Datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a version of this by sorting your `AdvancedDataGrid`'s `dataProvider` in reverse order of the scheme you describe. It will be a series of sort operations. First sort by date, then product, then contact-person, then finally sorting on company. If your `AdvancedDataGrid` has sortable columns, however, user interaction could immediately mess this up.

Comment: its Very nice, can give some example for this problem. Thanks for idea given to me. if u give some example it is more useful to me